# JSON.LOADS is picking only 2 resultset

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use JSON to search through googlemapapi. So, I give location "Plymouth" - in googlemapapi it is showing 6 resultset but when I try to parse in Json, I am getting length of only 2. I tried with multiple cities too, but all I am getting is resultset of 2 rather.
What is wrong below?

```
import urllib.request as UR
import urllib.parse as URP
import json

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Plymouth&sensor=false"
uh = UR.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
count = 0

js1 = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8') )
print ("Length: ", len(js1))
for result in js1:
    location = js1["results"][count]["formatted_address"]
    lat = js1["results"][count]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js1["results"][count]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    count = count + 1

    print ('lat',lat,'lng',lng)
    print (location)
```

Comment: Why are you not using result in your for loop?

Comment: If I simply use result["formatted_address"], it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `for result in js1:` with `for result in js1['results']:`

---

By the way, as posted in a comment in the question, no need to use a counter. You can rewrite your `for` loop as:

```
for result in js1['results']:
    location = result["formatted_address"]
    lat = result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]

    print('lat',lat,'lng',lng)
    print(location)
```

Comment: Hi @python_beginner, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark (not just upvoting). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the json that comes in, you'll see that its a single `dict` with two items (`"results"` and `"status"`). Add `print('result:', result)` to the top of your for loop and it will print `result: status` and `result: results` because all you are iterating the the keys of that outer dict. That's a general debugging trick in python... if you aren't getting the stuff you want, put in a print statement to see what you got.

The results (not surprisingly) and in a `list` under `js1["results"]`. In your `for` loop, you ignore the variable you are iterating and go back to the original `js1` for its data. This is unnecessary and in your case, it hid the error. Had you tried to reference cities off of `result` you would gotten an error and it may have been easier to see that `result` was `"status"`, not the array you were after.

Now a few tweaks fix the problem

```
import urllib.request as UR
import urllib.parse as URP
import json

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Plymouth&sensor=false"
uh = UR.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
count = 0

js1 = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8') )
print ("Length: ", len(js1))
for result in js1["results"]:
    location = result["formatted_address"]
    lat = result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    count = count + 1

    print ('lat',lat,'lng',lng)
    print (location)
```